# TypeORM Entity Relationship Setup Issue: Entity Metadata Not Found

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with NestJS, and am running into an Entity definition issue.

I have two entities, one called `Record` and one called `Log`. Each `Record` can have 0 to many `Log`s. Because of that relationship, I set up the entities like this (with other fields removed for brevity):

```
// log.entity.ts
export class Log {
  @ManyToOne(() => Record, (record) => record.logs)
  record!: Record;
}

// record.entity.ts
export class Record {
  @OneToMany(() => Log, (log) => log.record)
  logs!: Log[];
}
```

This is similar to relationships I have on other entities, which are all working just fine. However, when I try to start the app I get the following error:

```bash
TypeORMError: Entity metadata for Record#logs was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
    at projects/my-project/node_modules/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1106:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (projects/my-project/node_modules/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1096:34)
    at projects/my-project/node_modules/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (projects/my-project/node_modules/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
    at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (projects/my-project/node_modules/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DataSource.buildMetadatas (projects/my-project/node_modules/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:704:13)
    at async DataSource.initialize (projects/my-project/node_modules/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:259:13)
```

I made sure that both entities are included in the NestJS module:

```
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
  Person,
  SalaryLog,
  SalaryRecord,
  SalaryParalegalInfo,
  SalaryCalculationConfig,
]),
```

The import for `Record` in `log.entity.ts` points to the correct file for the `Record`, and vice versa for `Log`. I've looked through several StackOverflow questions and tried several things but can't seem to get it working. If I remove the relationship on the `Record` side and leave it on the `Log` side, things run as expected.

Any suggestions for configuring the Entities correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons why this error appears, but in my case the issue was that the `Log` entity didn't have the `@Entity()` decorator, which caused the issue.